# For a Banach space $X$, when is $X$ homeomorphic to $X \setminus A$?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces

$\mathbb{R}^n\not\cong\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ are not homeomorphic is a triviality from Algebraic Topology. On the other hand, if $X$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space, then $X \cong X\setminus\{0\}$.

> **Question.** In the $\infty$-dimensional spaces, which sets are "removable" like $\{0\}$ in $X$? Can you give an explicit homeomorphic map in such a case?

Comment: Wow, $X \simeq X \setminus \{0\}$, really? Do you have a reference for that? Or is getting the reference part of the question?

Comment: V.  Klee, Two topological properties of  topological linear spaces, Israel J.  Math. 4  (1964), 211-220.

Comment: I suggest that the title should be changed to better reflect the question

Comment: I changed the title.  Feel free to edit further if you don't like it.  I thought $\setminus$ would be clearer since $-$ is ambiguous in a vector space.

Comment: There is a huge literature on this. Start with MR0250342  
Henderson, David W.
Infinite-dimensional manifolds are open subsets of Hilbert space. 
Topology 9 1970 25–33.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/254521/producing-non-trivial-homotopy-classes-in-infty-dimensional-vector-spaces-by/254550?noredirect=1#comment626776_254550 and references therein

Comment: Many know but let me still write that there is entire well-developed branch devoted to this kind of questions. This branch is the infinite dimensional topology. There were pioneering Scottish Book questions by Karol Borsuk. You may call it pre-history. Then there were early pioneers: Anderson, Bessaga, Henderson, Klee, Szankowski, ... Then there were the very advanced, outstanding results by Chapman, Toruńczyk, West, followed by R. D. Edwards, etc.

Comment: Van Mill 's book "Prerequisites and an introduction" (see https://www.amazon.com/Infinite-Dimensional-Prerequisites-Introduction-North-Holland-Mathematical/dp/0444871330) shows that for separable Banach spaces $X$ ,$X$ is homeomorphic to $X \setminus A$, where $A$ is a Z-set (defined in the book), Z-sets include all $\sigma$-compact subsets of $X$. I was quite suprised when I first learnt this.. There won't be easy explicit homeomorphisms though. For $\{0\}$ there is, see Bessaga and Pelczynski's fine book.